# mlogit gives error: the two indexes don't define unique observations

Tags: r, mlogit

My dataframe named `longData` looks like:

```
  ID Set Choice Apple Microsoft IBM Google Intel HewlettPackard Sony Dell Yahoo Nokia
1  1   1      0     1         0   0      0     0              0    0    0     0     0
2  1   2      0     0         1   0      0     0              0    0    0     0     0
3  1   3      0     0         0   1      0     0              0    0    0     0     0
4  1   4      1     0         0   0      1     0              0    0    0     0     0
5  1   5      0     0         0   0      0     0              0    0    0     0     1
6  1   6      0    -1         0   0      0     0              0    0    0     0     0
```

I am trying to run mlogit on it by:

```
logitModel = mlogit(Choice ~ Apple+Microsoft+IBM+Google+Intel+HewlettPackard+Sony+Dell+Yahoo+Nokia | 0, data = longData, shape = "long")
```

it gives the following error:

```
Error in dfidx::dfidx(data = data, dfa$idx, drop.index = dfa$drop.index,  : 
  the two indexes don't define unique observations
```

after looking for some time I found that this error was given by `dfidx` as seen in [here](https://rdrr.io/cran/dfidx/src/R/dfidx.R) as:

```
z <- data[, c(posid1[1], posid2[1])]
if (nrow(z) != nrow(unique(z)))
    stop("the two indexes don't define unique observations")
```

but upon calling the following code, it runs without the error and gives the names of two idx that are uniquely able to identify a row in dataframe:

```
dfidx(longData)$idx
```

this gives expected output as:

```
~~~ indexes ~~~~
   ID Set
1   1   1
2   1   2
3   1   3
4   1   4
5   1   5
6   1   6
7   1   7
8   1   8
9   1   9
10  1  10
indexes:  1, 2
```

So what am I doing wrong, I saw some related questions [1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62181059/error-with-using-mlogit-r-function-the-two-indexes-dont-define-unique-observa), [2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62775764/error-with-using-the-mlogit-r-function-the-two-indexes-dont-define-unique-obse) but couldn't find what I am missing.

Answer (score 1):

It looks like your example comes from here: https://docs.displayr.com/wiki/MaxDiff_Analysis_Case_Study_Using_R

The code seems outdated, I remember it worked for me, but not anymore.

The error message is valid because every pair (ID, Set) appears several times, once for each alternative.

However this works:

```
# there will be complaint that choice can't be coerced to logical otherwise
longData$Choice <- as.logical(longData$Choice)
# create alternative number (nAltsPerSet is 5 in this example)
longData$Alternative <- 1+( 0:(nrow(longData)-1) %% nAltsPerSet)
# define dataset
mdata <- mlogit.data(data=longData,shape="long", choice="Choice",alt.var="Alternative",id.var="ID")
# model
logitModel = mlogit(Choice ~ Microsoft+IBM+Google+Intel+HewlettPackard+Sony+Dell+Yahoo+Nokia | 0,
                    data = mdata
)

summary(logitModel)
```